# What is the name of this plant? It has round big flowers

Tags: identification, flowering, ornamental-plant

I am sorry if this is too vague. May I know the name of this plant? The flower should look like a big round circle. The color is blue or pink if I recall correctly.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd rather say this is an ornamental [Aillium](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allium).

They often use it to decorate my town. Here is how the head will look like if I'm not wrong:

[image: ornamental aillium]

Might be a *giganteum*; in below picture you'll notice similar leaves.

[image]

Comment: Could also be Allium 'Gladiator' or Allium 'Globemaster' as well as A. giganteum...

Comment: certainly some allium.

Answer (score 1):

I would say Agapanthus, for the long stalk, but the leaves usually have not so much width.

Comment: I disagree with your id. Quite similar though.